# Is there a way to host DevExpress controls in MFC Application?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, mfc, devexpress

We have MFC windows application already hosted in a system and want to add report generating module to it using DevExpress Reporting tool. Since DevExpress doesn't support MFC directly but works with .Net, so work around is to make MFC and .NET to talk to each other. What approach yields this kind of implementation? Any reference to implement this type of functionality/roadmap?

Upon quick research, one of the way to do this is make a C#-Wrapper(which includes DevExpress components) and giving callbacks from MFC.

Comment: If the set of DevExpress controls you're planning to use are based on Windows Forms, you can use MFC's hosting support (see [Using a Windows Form User Control in MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/using-a-windows-form-user-control-in-mfc)).